# Saving current element styling to a variable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<style>
#testSubject{
  color: red;
  width: 200px;
}
</style>

<p id="testSubject">Hello, world!</p>
```

With jQuery / vanilla JS, is there any way to save the currently active styling of the element to a variable, so that it may be restored/used later?

ie: `var testSubjectStyles = $('#testSubject').css('*');`

now I have the variable `testSubjectStyles`, and can apply those stylings to any element.

Is it possible to do this? I've been playing around with jQuery's `.css()`, but that only seems to let you set stylings.

Comment: i have given a simple answer using .css() method of jquery to extract css of an element in to a variable and apply it to another element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `var yourvar=element.css();` to get an object containing all element specific standard markup. If you also need vendor markup, check out this more complex solution:

[Taken from Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/6416527#6416527)

```
function getStyleObject(stobj){
        var dom = stobj.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            };
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            };
            return returns;
        };
        if(style = dom.currentStyle){
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            };
            return returns;
        };
        return stobj.css();
    }
```

Then just use `var yourstyle=getStyleObject(source);`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have to get backgroundColor of an element and apply it to another element

```
var testSubjectStyles = $('#testSubject').css('backgroundColor');
$("#anotherelement").css('backgroundColor',testSubjectStyles);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or you could just use `var yourvar=yourelement.css()` to get an object containing all markup for that element.

Comment: @RenéRoth That would be an error...

Comment: what made someone downvote my answer can anybody correct where i was misled

Comment: Seems like somebody was having a bad day and downvoting all answers.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with JavaScript, you don't need to use jQuery.

```
var testSubjectStyles = $('#textSubject')[0].style;
```

That will give you a full CSSStyleDeclaration object, which includes all the css properties for the element.

Comment: does this just include CSS set via the `style=` attribute, or does it include CSS in external stylesheets?

Comment: It includes all the css properties active in the element, wherever they came from

Comment: Nope: http://jsfiddle.net/MkYj2/

Comment: isn't that jquery ?